# Angular2 Reusing Components

Tags: angular

I have common components in my app like header, dialogBox, etc that I use in other components. They way I do it right now is I simply use them as HTML tags whenever I need. For example if my header component's selector is `'app-header'`, everytime I want to include header I use `<app-header></app-header>`.

I feel like this is not the right way of doing it, because Angular has thing called ViewChild which supposedly do the same thing. However, when I try to use ViewChild I get the same error as discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415

Answer (score 0):

Looks, like your problem is completely different from the problem from issue 5415 (your link)..

If you want to have always some components on your page and just some replacement - you need to use a Router.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Imagine I have 3 components: HomeComponent, MapComponent, TileComponent. I want HomeCompoent View to include MapComponent and TileComponent at all the times. I do not think this is what router is for.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the problem from your explanation..

If you need one component to include another component, just add them to a HomeComponent template (and 'directives' property of decorator), like this:

`    ...
    <map-component></map-component>
    <title-component></title-component>
   ...
`

and than you will put your <home-component> somewhere it will render inside all child components.. it is the basic principle of component-based approach.

`@ViewChild` decorator is only necessary when you wanna get an access to properties of child component

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. That is the way I was doing. I just was not sure that it is the proper angular way of doing it.

Comment: You are welcome! )
This is exactly the proper new angular way

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the child component selectors in the template for the parent component. Once done this way, the child components will appear whenever you use the parent component. I have been doing this in my angular 2 projects and this works. Let me know if my understanding about your problem is correct. 
Cheers,
Abhi